# postgresql export database by command or pgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-3, data-backup

I want to export my postgresql db with pgadmin.
I search all of its GUI, I also searched the web and I don't find some sueful information.
I know how to import the db into postgresql: create a db with `template0' and then:

```
 c:\program files\postgresql\9.3\bin> psql -h localhost -p 5432 
                                -U postgres newDBname < D:\backup.sql
```

But I don't know how to export it.
please help me to export my db.

Comment: Are you looking to backup/copy to a new server? How do you feel about command line?

Comment: yes, but I think it does not matter !

Comment: Look at the Tools menu in pgAdmin3. Do you see there "Backup" and "Restore" as I do?

Comment: It is disabled !

Comment: Do you have Administrator Rights to the system on the PostGres user you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was that I could not find the `pg_dump` command. I thought it was a subcommand of `psql` command.
You need to add `c:\program files\postgresql\9.3\bin>` to `path`(system variables) of windows or use its direct executable file:

## export:

```
c:\program files\postgresql\9.3\bin> pg_dump.exe -U postgres test2 >"d:\backup.sql"
```

## import:

```
c:\program files\postgresql\9.3\bin> psql -h localhost -p 5432  -U postgres newDBname < D:\backup.sql
```

## export special table:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --format plain --ignore-version --verbose --file "C:\temp\filename.backup" --table public.tablename dbname
```

Comment: Yeh, me too when I started out. I was surprised to see how simple it was. To test it I created a dummy database and put data into it, backed it up, dropped the database and then restored - everything worked as before so I adopted that procedure... I've only needed to restore from backup twice (RAID failure) and both times it's worked - much better than starting again!

Answer (score 3):

The pair that you want is [PG_Dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html) and [PG_Restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html)...

I use PG_Dump on a scheduled task to backup our PostGIS databases in a format that can be restored easily - and more importantly will work!

```
pg_dump.exe --file=c:\Your\path\BACKUP_Name.Backup -Fc -Z9 -o DatabaseName
```

- Custom format
- Z9 compression (to save space)
- Include objectIDs

and then to restore on the other end..

Create a new empty database with the correct name and run:

```
pg_restore -c -Fc -d DatabaseName c:\Your\path\BACKUP_Name.Backup
```

- clean the database first
- Custom format

Works for me... but as with anything TEST IT FIRST, just because it works for me in PostGIS/SDE on this version doesn't guarantee it will work for you in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

For PostGIS, make sure you are following the [hard upgrade procedure](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade):

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -Fc -b -v -f file.backup thedatabase
```

This way it can be restored in the existing database, or it can be discovered with a future version of PostGIS using the `postgis_restore.pl` command. For Windows, you need to tailor a simple BAT file [described here](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiWinUpgrade). Note that this is similar to the `pg_restore` utility described by other answers, but is specifically tailored to PostGIS.

Comment: Good advice Mike, I'll look into that... Does it work for SDE databases that use PG_GEOMETRY? Will that help upgrade from one version to the next version? Previously I have upgraded by using Catalog to backup features to fGDB and then Esri copy to the new database - this could be a simpler procedure.

Comment: I don't know much about SDE on PostgreSQL, but the `pg_geometry` data type will not be touched by PostGIS, just like any other data type, and will be restored on a host DB only if the `pg_geometry` datatype exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a graphical user interface, you can use pgAdmin III (gratis, Linux/Windows/OS X). Simply right click on the table of your choice, then "backup". It will create a `pg_dump` command for you, if latter on you want to do it with CLI.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]